# forEach function returns undefined for some reason

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I wanna create a function that takes two arguments : first one the itemsArray , and the second one the itemName. then this function should return true or false depending on weather the itemsArray includes itemName or not.

I used the high order array method *forEach* but it keeps returning undefined for some reason...

I wanna know why ?

note: I already came up with other solutions to make this function work, but I wanna know the reason why this particular function returns undefined.. if someone could explain to me it would be much appreciated

```js
let items = ['item-1','item-2','item-3','item-4'];

function itemExist(itemList, itemName) {
  itemList.forEach( (item) => {
    return item === itemName
  })
}

console.log(itemExist(items, 'item-3')) // expected output: true

console.log(itemExist(items, 'item-5')) // expected output: false

// it return undefined instead ?
```

ter code here

Comment: [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) returns undefined, you need [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) -- `function itemExist(itemList, itemName) { return itemList.includes(itemName)};`

Comment: You could have simply used something like indexOf here. If you are doing this for practice you should know that you are not returning anything from your function. One hint would be to have a variable outside the forEach which becomes true once your array element is found in forEach. Then you could return that variable.

Comment: @pilchard I wanna know the reason why it returns undefined

Comment: You're returning a value of bool from ```forEach```, but you're not returning anything from your actual function. If you wanna keep this approach, you can assign the returning result in a variable inside your function. then return that variable. Or maybe you can try ```Array.protytype.some```, ```Array.prototype.indexOf``` or ```Array.prototype.includes```.

Comment: You can't return out of a `forEach` (each iteration is simply running the callback you passed it, the return value is not used by the enclosing forEach) and `forEach` itself returns undefined by definition,  (see earlier link to the docs). If you want to return out of the iteration you need to use a `for` loop. Otherwise you need to declare a variable outside the `forEach` assign it from within the loop, and return it afterwards

Comment: @TusharShahi As mentioned in the question I did have came up with many other solutions but for the sake of understanding I wanted to know the reason behind my funtion's behaviour..

Comment: Thank you guys that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason you get undefined is because you are returning from forEach and not from itemExist() function.

The way you would implement the following case using forEach is as follows:

```
let items = ['item-1','item-2','item-3','item-4'];

function itemExist(itemList, itemName) {
  let isItemPresent = false;
  itemList.forEach( (item) => {
    if(item === itemName) {
        isItemPresent = true;
        return;
    }
  })
  if(isItemPresent) {
      return true;  
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(itemExist(items, 'item-3')) // expected output: true

console.log(itemExist(items, 'item-5')) // expected output: false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = ['item-1','item-2','item-3','item-4'];

function itemExist(itemList, itemName) {

 // forEach wouldn't return anything
 // forEach internal function didn't return out you from outer function 
 itemList.forEach( (item) => {
    return item === itemName
  })

  /* if you won't return anything your function 
    it will return undefined by default 
   */
}

console.log(itemExist(items, 'item-3')) // expected output: undefined
console.log(itemExist(items, 'item-5')) // expected output: undefined


// correct way
console.log(items.includes('item-3')) // true
console.log(items.includes('item-5')) // true 
console.log(items.includes('item-9')) // false
```